# How to QThread in PyQT

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, pyqt5, pyside2

I am having a lot of trouble with my code - specifically, implementing some sort of signal/slot/threading. I am new to this and the things I read online have not been too helpful.

Anyways, I used PyQT Designer to make a simple GUI. This is what it is:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(687, 514)
        self.browse_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.browse_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 440, 61, 27))
        self.browse_btn.setObjectName("browse_btn")
        self.play_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.play_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 440, 61, 27))
        self.play_btn.setObjectName("play_btn")
        self.cur_scene_header = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.cur_scene_header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 191, 21))
        self.cur_scene_header.setObjectName("cur_scene_header")
        self.prev_scene_header = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.prev_scene_header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 191, 21))
        self.prev_scene_header.setObjectName("prev_scene_header")
        self.pause_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pause_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 440, 61, 27))
        self.pause_btn.setObjectName("pause_btn")
        self.reset_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.reset_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 440, 61, 27))
        self.reset_btn.setObjectName("reset_btn")
        self.prev_scenes = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.prev_scenes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 120, 331, 301))
        self.prev_scenes.setObjectName("prev_scenes")
        self.current_scene = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.current_scene.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 331, 31))
        self.current_scene.setObjectName("current_scene")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, -1))
        self.browse_btn.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Browse", None, -1))
        self.play_btn.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Play", None, -1))
        self.cur_scene_header.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Sans Serif\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Current Scene</p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.prev_scene_header.setHtml(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'Sans Serif\'; font-size:9pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">Previous Scenes</p></body></html>", None, -1))
        self.pause_btn.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Pause", None, -1))
        self.reset_btn.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Reset", None, -1))
```

Nothing really important there. There are four buttons: Browse, Play, Reset, and Pause. I have not yet immplemented the Reset and Pause buttons, but I will later on.

There are two QWidgetList. The first on, "curr_scene" (current scene), displays one string. The second one, "prev_scenes" is a list of previous scenes (past current_scenes).

When a user clicks the "Browse" button, they are allowed to choose a file (a csv file) using the TKinter filedialogue module. Once that is chosen, the program loads the content of the csv file. What I *want* to happen next is that it goes to the first row (of the csv file), puts that text in the current_scene List, then it waits fives seconds, sends that line to the previous_scene list, and then takes the next row from the csv file, puts it in current_scene, and so on, until it reaches the last one.

What is happening *now* is what I want - except it isn't *displayed*. It doesn't show that happening on the gui. I can only either get the prev_scene to display the text, or the current_scene to display the text, and not both, and this is done by using `repaint`.

I know I have to use Threading. But I really have no idea how. Can you show me? Here is the code for the rest of the program:

```
import sys
import PySide2
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
import pull_csv_data
import main
import time
from tkinter import filedialog

class MainDialog(QWidget, main.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.browse_btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.browse_for_file)
        self.list = []
        self.connect(self.play_btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.list_items)
        self.csv_path = ""
        self.file_watch = QFileSystemWatcher()

    def browse_for_file(self):
        if not self.list:
            self.csv_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
            self.list = pull_csv_data.pull_data(self.csv_path)
            self.update_watcher()

    def update_watcher(self):
        self.file_watch.addPath(self.csv_path)
        self.file_watch.connect(self.file_watch, SIGNAL('fileChanged(QString)'), self.update_list)

    def update_list(self):
        print("here1")
        old_list = self.list
        self.list = pull_csv_data.pull_data(self.csv_path)
        print("here2")
        if len(old_list) < len(self.list):
            for i in range(len(old_list), len(self.list)):
                item = QListWidgetItem(self.list[i][0])
                self.prev_scenes.addItem(item)
                print("here6")
        else:
            self.list = pull_csv_data.pull_data(self.csv_path)
            self.prev_scenes.clear()
            for i in self.list:
                item = QListWidgetItem(i[0])
                self.prev_scenes.addItem(item)

    def list_items(self):
        if self.prev_scenes.count() == 0:
            for i in self.list:
                item = QListWidgetItem(i[0])
                self.update_current(item)

    def update_current(self, item):
        self.current_scene.addItem(item)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.update_prev(item)
        self.current_scene.clear()


    def update_prev(self, item):
        print("hello")
        self.prev_scenes.addItem(item)
        self.prev_scenes.repaint()
        self.prev_scenes.repaint()



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainDialog()
form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is pull_csv_data:

```
def pull_data(file_path):
    king = []
    with open(file_path) as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        for row in csvReader:
            king.append(row)
    return king
```

Comment: What is pull_csv_data?

Comment: It is a function... let me post it. It only extracts the data from csv file and saves it in a list.

Comment: If it is a function, please put it.

Comment: You could give an example of the .csv file

Comment: @eyllanesc don't worry about the csv file... it is not relevant. Imagine you just have a list of 50 strings assigned to self.list.

Comment: If you know it is irrelevant because you do not put it that way from the beginning, make life easy for us. Another thing, why do you use tkinter instead of using a QFileDialog?

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh, I did not realize it had a QFileDialog. I will use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to combine libraries that perform the same task, and worse libraries that can be blocked as `tkinter` and `Qt` and both create an internal mainloop. Qt is a library that has components for many things and also has it to select files: `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`

```
def browse_for_file(self):
    if not self.list:
        self.csv_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.list = pull_csv_data.pull_data(self.csv_path)
        self.update_watcher()
```

Another thing that should not be done is to do blocking tasks such as `sleep()`, these tasks do not let the GUI work, each GUI library proposes options for not having to use those functions, and in our case the combination of [`QEvenLoop`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html) with `QTimer` is the right option In addition you can not assign an item from one `QListWidget` to another, you must first remove it from one with [`takeItem()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#takeItem) and assign it to the other:

```
def update_current(self, item):
    self.current_scene.addItem(item)
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(500, loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    it = self.current_scene.takeItem(0)
    self.update_prev(it)

def update_prev(self, item):
    self.prev_scenes.addItem(item)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Do you have some good resources to learn threading from? And when should I use it? I am woried that I thought I should be using it here when I didn't have to

Comment: Basic Qt rule: the GUI should not be updated directly from a different thread than the main thread, this thread is called the GUI thread: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread, And in your case you wanted to do so look for another option, with the above I do not mean that you can not update the GUI with data from another thread, but you must use signals, or maybe QMetaObject::invokeMethod, also I recommend using the threads or classes related to Qt and not using threads of another type, for example QThread, QRunnable, QThreadPool.

Comment: The Qt documentation is very good so I recommend you read it.